# Script will not write multiple lines in csv

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, nested-loops

My script goes through every line of one csv (schema), and compares those values to every line of another csv (data). when it finds a match, it should write the whole row from the data file to a new file (out). As of now when I run it, it only writes the first match into the out file.

```
with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/c/out.csv", "w", newline="") as write:
    wtr = csv.writer(write)
    with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/c/schema.csv", "r") as schema:
        rdr = csv.reader(schema)
        with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/c/data.csv","r") as data:
            dat = csv.reader(data)
            for r in rdr:
                for d in dat:
                    if(r[0] == d[16] and r[1] == d[20]):
                        wtr.writerow(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read the whole data.csv file for each row in schema.csv, so you need to move the `open("...") as data` instruction inside the `for r in rdr:` loop:

```
with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/c/out.csv", "w", newline="") as write:
    wtr = csv.writer(write)
    with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/c/schema.csv", "r") as schema:
        rdr = csv.reader(schema)
        for r in rdr:
            with open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/c/data.csv","r") as data:
                dat = csv.reader(data)
                for d in dat:
                    if(r[0] == d[16] and r[1] == d[20]):
                        wtr.writerow(d)
```

**Edit:**

Just to explain a bit more, in your code you first initialize two `rdr` and `dat` iterators. Then you start looping over `rdr`, and for its first element, you start looping over all elements in `dat`.

Once this is done, the outer loop goes to the second element of `rdr`, and start looping again over `dat`, which is now empty. So nothing happens, and it keeps looping over `rdr` for nothing.